# How to check if FTP server offers TLS support in python?

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

How can I check if a FTP server allows for TLS when I connect using ftplib? I Found easy documentation on how to use TLS, but no solution on how to check for it. My script is supposed to connect either way, but use TLS if possible.

So do I just connect using TLS and if it fails I do it without? I am sure there must be a better way.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

*Note that trying an encryption only, is **as bad as not using any encryption at all**. And maybe even worse, as it gives an impression of security, while there's none.*

*When you are under an MITM attack, an attacker will divert a TCP traffic to him/her and simulate encryption rejection, making you send your credentials plain-text straight to the attacker.*

---

Anyway:

- Call [`FTP_TLS.auth`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP_TLS.auth), check if it throws or not.
- Call [`FTP_TLS.login` with `secure=False`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.4.6/Lib/ftplib.py#l742).

If the server supports TLS, the `FTP_TLS.auth` will enable encryption and the `FTP_TLS.login` (even with `secure=False`) will continue using it. If the server does not support encryption, the `FTP_TLS.login` (with `secure=False`) continues unencrypted.

*Note that `FTP_TLS.login` (with its `secure` parameter) is an undocumented method - If you do not want to use it, you can fallback to creating a plain [`FTP`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP), when `FTP_TLS.auth` throws.*

---

To check explicitly, you can also use [`FTP.voidcmd('FEAT')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.voidcmd) and look for `AUTH TLS` (or `AUTH SSL`) in the response.

But there's nothing wrong about trying `AUTH TLS`/`AUTH SSL` (what the `FTP_TLS.auth` does) straight away.

Comment: The docs do not mention "secure=False" https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ftplib.html . Is that depricated?

Comment: While it's not documented, it's there: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/ftplib.py#l667. And anyway with `secure=False` it's the same as calling the documented `FTP.login(self, user = '', passwd = '', acct = '')`.